# how to call function every time the current time is equal to time in my row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have column "date" in my table.I need to call my function for this table every time when the current time is equal to time in my "date" column. I don't know if it's possible to do this in ms sql server?

Comment: getDate() helps you getting the current date/time , post that use your logic to compare it with your column

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to implement some kind of scheduling.

You could try implementing one using one of SQL Server services called [*SQL Server Agent*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx). It may not be fit for *all* kinds of response to time events, though, but it should be able to manage certain tasks.

You would need to set up a SQL Server Agent *job* for it.

A job would need to consist of at least one *job step* and have at least one *schedule* to be runnable. Perhaps, it would be easiest for you at this point to use the *Transact-SQL* type of job step.

A Transact-SQL job step is just a Transact-SQL script, a multi-statement query. In your case it would probably first check if there are rows matching the current time. Then, either for every matching row separately or for the entire set of them, it would perform whatever kind of operation Transact-SQL allows you to perform.